# File hosting service similar to drop.io (but self-hosted and free/libre)

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps, sharing, self-hosted

I want to offer a file hosting service on my own server (GNU/Linux) that allows to upload files on the fly.

The web app must be FLOSS.

A [drop.io](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop.io) clone would be the best, but I don’t require all the features it offered.

#### Uploading files

Sign-up/sign-in must not be mandatory, so users should be able to stay anonymous.

1. Every user should be able to create a new **page** (with a dedicated/stable URL).
   `http://file-hosting.example.org/oHg5SJYRHA0`
2. Each page allows this user to upload **files**.
   `http://file-hosting.example.org/oHg5SJYRHA0/license.txt`
   `http://file-hosting.example.org/oHg5SJYRHA0/me.png`
3. The user can **configure** this page:

   - ***Restrict access?***
     *No*: Others only need the URL to access the page and download files.
     *Yes*: Others need the URL and the password to access the page and download files.
   - ***Expiration?***
     *No*: The page/files will be available forever.
     *Yes*: The page/files will be deleted after a specific configurable time.

It would be great if it’s possible for users to provide an **owner password** when creating a new page (optionally). This would allow them to change settings or delete/upload files even after their session is closed. If no owner password is provided, no-one can change anything.

#### Administrating the service

A web interface is not required, I’m fine with configuring it via SSH.

- It should be possible to set the **maximum file size**.
- It should be possible to set a **global maximum** (totalized size of all uploaded files).
- It should be possible to **notify** the admin about new pages and new files somehow (e.g., via e-mail or XMPP or feed …).

Comment: I am going to make something like that (because of this inspiration) but it won't be done soon, I am not the best with backend yet.

Comment: Maybe the community could write an open source platform on github.com and I will host it!

Comment: Have you considered using ownCloud? It does not support exactly your specifications, but you might be able to change the source, or work around them as needed.

Comment: @Marcel: Do you know ownCloud good enough so that you could describe which features it fulfills and which features it misses? It would make a useful answer, even if it’s only a partial solution (especially because there don’t seem to be better matches yet).

Answer (score 3):

ownCloud (https://owncloud.org/) does match at least somewhat:

- It requires signup, but you could always create a "public" user with no/public password
- It's free and open source (AGPL-licensed, AFAIK) https://github.com/owncloud
- It's selfhosted, as far as nothing else as web server (e.g. apache) and a DB (MariaDB, MySQL or SQLite) is required.
- Sharing of files and directories, with or without link
- Setting of quotas

It does not support (AFAIK)

- The "page per user" requirement.
- The expiration of files